# Fourier transform of some particular function

Tags: definite-integrals, special-functions, fourier-transform, bessel-functions

Sir,
I tried to find out the fourier transform of the following function: $\frac{\exp ik_0\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}$ such as the integral :
$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp -ikx \times \frac{\exp ik_0\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}\, dx $

Where $a$ and $k_0$ are constants, but I cant do this. Would you kindly help me or suggest any relevant references from where I can get some help.